# Why does the placement of the } determine the outcome?

Tags: javascript

I am trying find the longest word in the provided sentence, and return the length of that word.

I originally wrote this function:

```
 function findLongestWord(str) {
      var myArray = str.split(' '); 
      var longest=0; 
      for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
        if(myArray[i].length>longest) {
          longest = myArray[i].length; 
        }
        return longest; 
      }
    }

findLongestWord('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'); returns 3.
```

Then I moved the second-to-last curly brace so that it looked like this:

```
   function findLongestWord(str) {
      var myArray = str.split(' '); 
      var longest=0; 
      var word = null; 
      for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
        if(myArray[i].length>longest) {
           longest = myArray[i].length; 
    }
  }
    return longest; 
}
findLongestWord('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'); returns 6.
```

Can anyone explain why exactly the first function returns 3? What does the 3 represent?

Answer (score 3):

On the first code, you're not done with the for loop and so the return break the loop and return the first word length while in the second code you return the result when you loop is done and so you get the right result.

Answer (score 2):

In the first function, the return statement is inside the for loop, so it will return the length of the first word, which is "The" and so will return 3. Whereas the second one will correctly return the length of the longest word.

Answer (score 1):

In the first version, you return on the first iteration of the for loop, regardless of what happens. In the second version, you don't return until the for loop has finished. That's why the result is different. The returned value is the length of the string from `myArray[i].length`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you return the variable **longest** inside the for-loop. This will cause execution to leave the function. So the function returns 3 because it only iterates the first element of the array, which is the word 'The'.

Good luck!